# Find image when click button use jquery parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I starting learning jQuery, but I can't do this after I tried many times.
I want find image when click button use jquery parent. This is my html code:

```
<div class="list-item">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto item-food-img">
        <button class="inline">
            <img src="/uploads/1/food.jpg" alt="bread" width="60" height="60">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col item-food-info">
        <div class="item-food-name">bread</div>
        <div class="item-order-time">Ordered <span class="font-weight-bold">1</span> times</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto item-food-add">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto item-price">
                27,000 <span class="unit">đ</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <span class="btn-adding">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
$(this).parents('.list-item .row')).find('img')
```

Comment: `but I can't do this after I tried many times` What did you try? Post your code and we'd be happy to have a look and help if we can.

Comment: this is my js code: $(this).parents('.list-item .row')).find('img')

Comment: this is not clear . try to show your full code and more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of these 2 code parts

```
$("button.inline").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".list-item").find("img");
});

$("button.inline").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img");
});
```

Your code:

```
$(this).parents('.list-item .row')).find('img')
                                  ^
                                  What is this doing here?
```

Now let's break down this part `$(this).parents('.list-item .row')`.

`$(this)` represent your button that you click on, so `.parents('.list-item .row')` will not work since the button's parent element don't have the class `list-item`

**Demo**

```js
$("button.inline").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto item-food-img">
      <button class="inline">
            <img src="/uploads/1/food.jpg" alt="bread" width="60" height="60">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col item-food-info">
      <div class="item-food-name">bread</div>
      <div class="item-order-time">Ordered <span class="font-weight-bold">1</span> times</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto item-food-add">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto item-price">
          27,000 <span class="unit">đ</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <span class="btn-adding">+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank u so much! But I want find image when I click .btn-adding class